# struct as return value not compiling/running

Tags: c

I am currently learning C and this is also my first question here.
The problem is as follows. I get this warning when I try to compile this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LicenseManager.h"

int main(void)
{
    puts("program start");
    struct License *license = read();
    // other code
}
```

The `read()` Method is in LicenseManager.h declared as `struct License *read(void){...}` and the pointer it returns is a reference to `static struct License license;`, but when I try to compile the compiler refuses and says

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'read'
> [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
> struct License *license = read();

Even my IDE says that the `read()`; method returns an int (when i look at it in the main method, in the actual LicenseManager.h it the IDE correctly says `struct License *`.

What I tried:
I tried making a Method prototype `struct License *read(void);` above the main method

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LicenseManager.h"

struct License read();

int main(void)
{
    puts("program start");
    struct License *license = read();
    // other code
}
```

, which resolved that error and got the code to compile, however now I instantly get a

> Segmentation Fault

(even before `puts("program start");` is invoked).

I tried to change the returnvalue of `read()` from a pointer to an actual struct, however that raised the same problems.

Next I tried to change the `read()` method to `void read(struct License *license)` and give the pointer to the object externally but I still receive the same Segementation Fault every time. before the first line of code is even invoked.

after everything I tried my final code now looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LicenseManager.h"

void read(struct License *license);

int main(void)
{
    puts("program start");
    struct License license;
    read(&license);
}
```

Needless to say. it still does not run. :( what do I do wrong?

---

So I found out some stuff, thanks to you guys and through some testing.
When I use my MingW64 (i am running on windows) console I get Segmentation fault. I wanted to avoid posting large amounts of code here. but I guess I will do it. The Library i am using is an Open source Json lib called [cJSON](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON)

.
LicenseManager.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cJSON.c"
#include "cJSON.h"
#include "LicenseManager.h"
#include <time.h>

#define JSON_FILE "license.json"
void interpret(cJSON *json, struct License *license);

// DEFINE VALUES IN JSON FILE
const char *LICENSE_NAME = "printerLicense";
const char *LICENSE_COMPANY_NAME = "name";
const char *LICENSE_PRINTER_ID = "id";
const char *LICENSE_VALID_START = "validFrom";
const char *LICENSE_VALID_END = "validTo";
const char *LICENSE_PERMISSIONS = "permissions";
const char *LICENSE_HARDWARE_ID = "hardwareId";
//############################

char *readFile(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(JSON_FILE, "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);
    char *string = malloc(fsize + 1);
    fread(string, 1, fsize, f);
    fclose(f);
    string[fsize] = 0;
    return string;
}

void parseDate(cJSON *json, struct Date *date)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    unsigned short valYear, valMonth, valDay;
    cJSON *child = json;
    valYear = child->valueint;
    child = child->next;
    valMonth = child->valueint;
    child = child->next;
    valDay = child->valueint;
    date->year = &valYear;
    date->month = &valMonth;
    date->day = &valDay;
}

void setLicenseRights(cJSON *json, struct License *license)
{
    cJSON *rights = get_Array_item(json, LICENSE_PERMISSIONS, cJSON_False);
    int size = cJSON_GetArraySize(rights);
    char *permissions[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        permissions[i] = get_array_item(rights, i);
    }
    memcpy(license->permissions, permissions, sizeof(permissions));
}

void interpret(cJSON *json, struct License *license)
{
    cJSON *licenseJson = json->child;
    struct Date validFrom;
    parseDate(get_object_item(licenseJson, LICENSE_VALID_START, cJSON_False), &validFrom);
    struct Date validTo;
    parseDate(get_object_item(licenseJson, LICENSE_VALID_END, cJSON_False), &validTo);
    cJSON *companyName = get_object_item(licenseJson, LICENSE_COMPANY_NAME, cJSON_False);
    cJSON *hardwareID = get_object_item(licenseJson, LICENSE_HARDWARE_ID, cJSON_False);
    cJSON *printerID = get_object_item(licenseJson, LICENSE_PRINTER_ID, cJSON_False);
    setLicenseRights(licenseJson, license);
    license->companyName = companyName->valuestring;
    license->hardwareID = hardwareID->valuestring;
    license->printerID = printerID->valuestring;
    license->validFrom = &validFrom;
    license->validTo = &validTo;
}
//reads the License file. Use this to read the License.
void read(struct License *license)
{
    printf("#####################\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    char *string = readFile();
    printf("#####################\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    cJSON *json = cJSON_Parse(string);
    printf("#####################\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    interpret(json, license);
    printf("#####################\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    cJSON_Delete(json);
    free(string);
}
```

LicenseManager.h

```
#ifndef DATE
#define DATE
struct Date
{
    unsigned int *year, *month, *day;
};
#endif

#ifndef LICENSE
#define LICENSE
struct License
{
    char *companyName;
    char *printerID;
    char *hardwareID;
    struct Date *validFrom;
    struct Date *validTo;
    char *permissions[];
};
#endif
```

and of course main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LicenseManager.h"

void read(struct License *license);

int main(void)
{
    puts("program start");
    fflush(stdout);
    struct License license;
    read(&license);
}
```

**I forgot to include the actual LicenseManager.c file in my main. now I get some other compiler errors which i am likely to be able to fix. So the compiler just assumed that the read method just returns an int, because there was no actual declaration of it. now I just have to deal with some incompatible pointers haha**.

Comment: The prototype `struct License read();` doesn't match how you use it. When you use it you assign the result to a *pointer* to `License`. Also note that the prototype says that the arguments to `read` are unknown. If you want to say that the function takes no arguments, then you explicitly need to use `void` as the arguments type.

Comment: There's also the problem that on POSIX systems (like Linux or macOS) there's a *system call* called `read`, which does something other than your function does, as well as using different parameters. That's why, in C, it's common to use prefixes to distinguish between functions. Like for example `license_read`.

Comment: the issue is probably in the `read` method that you're not showing

Comment: The most important thing is missing here: *how are you compiling this?* I suspect that you are just including the header, but that does not make the function magically available if the header only contains its signature. You also need its *definition*, which is likely in some other `.c` file that *needs* to be passed to the compiler along with yours.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli -- I don't think this is a linkage issue, because there's a warning from the compiler. As @Some programmer dude says, if you must -- for some reason -- provide your own function prototype, it has to be correct. I wonder -- is something in LicenseManager.h preventing the declaration of `read()` being processed? And who would call a function `read` anyway?

Comment: @KevinBoone declaration =/= definition. If as OP says the `.h` file only contains the *declaration*, then that's definitely not enough. You need the actual function. That's what I was thinking. We would also need to see the content of the `.h` file anyway. As it currently stands, there are not enough details to answer this.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli -- you're right that there's not enough information. And no doubt the implementation of the function will be needed at link time. However, it seems to me that things are going wrong before getting to that stage.

Comment: @KevinBoone you're right, the compiler warning implies a wrong declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning:

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'read'
> [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] struct License *license = read();

Is telling you that the explicit prototype provided does not match the prototype you tried to use:

```
struct License read();
```

Also, if this prototype is provided in the header file, it should not be re-declared in your source code.

Simply stated, the prototype of the function `read` needs to match its intended usage in the shown code:

Here is an adapted version of your code (with some additions to assist building on my system, i.e. a fake struct.)

```
// implementation of sample struct to allow build without "LicenseManager.h"
struct License 
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char account[80];
};

//again, because I do not have "LicenseManager.h", prototype provided here.
struct License *read(void);//corrected prototype

int main(void)
{
    puts("program start");
    struct License *license = read();//this usage dictates prototype needs of read()
    printf("%d\n%d\n%s", license->a, license->b, license->account);
    free(license);//free memory once no longer needed.
    return 0;

}

struct License *read(void)//example implementation but using proper prototype  
{
    struct License *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));//create memory
    //populate struct with some values:
    new->a = 10;
    new->b = 20;
    strcpy(new->account, "Bains");
    return new;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please provide the header code or at least just extract `read()` from there and post a complete program here**

#### A program using 3 versions for read()

Please compare the code below to your version and look at possible clues and ask about them

**The program shows**

```
Start
read() as "License read()" 35? : 35
read() as "License* read()" 9? : 9
read() as "void read(License*)" -56? : -56
End
```

**The code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { int i; } License;

License* pRead(void);
License read(void);
void readV(License* L);

int main(void)
{
    puts("Start");
    License license = read();
    printf("read() as \"License read()\" 35? : %d\n", license.i);
    License* p = pRead();
    printf("read() as \"License* read()\" 9? : %d\n", p->i);
    free(p);
    readV(&license);
    printf("read() as \"void read(License*)\" -56? : %d\n", license.i);
    puts("End");
    return 0;
};  // main()

License*    pRead()
{
    License* p = (License*)malloc(sizeof(License));
    p->i = 9;
    return p;
};

License read()
{
    License L = { 35 };
    return L;
};

void        readV(License* L) { L->i = -56; };
```

A small change from your code: a

```
    typedef struct { int i; } License;
```

was inserted in order to not repeat the keyword `struct` everywhere

Comment: oh that typedef looks very handy! I will definetely make use of that in the future.